# What if an argument has the same name as that of a data member?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, standards, datamember

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(int n) { std::cout << n; }
    int n{2};
};

int main()
{
    A a{1};
}
```

The output is `1` rather than `2`.

Does the C++ standard define that the argument name is preferred if it is the same as that of a data member?

Comment: Duplicating variable names is a really bad idea, even if it's technically legal in the language. It leads to confusion as to which variable you meant to use.

Comment: Read compiler warnings.

Comment: No warning by default options with clang 9.@MichaelChourdakis

Comment: @xmllmx then too bad. At all costs avoid shadowing an existing variable.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis no diagnostic required in case of shadowing. Most compilers won't do that even if all warnings enabled. Visual Studio is a special snowflake as far a I know, oriented onto nowbie code monkeys. GCC\clang require special flag for that exact warning, `-Wall -Wextra` won't do this.

Comment: @xmllmx Enable the flag `-Wshadow-all` This is a good flag to have, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is in a "closer" scope than the member variable, so the argument *shadows* the member variable.

The obvious solution is to rename the argument (or the member variable), so they are not the same anymore.

You can also use `this->n` to explicitly use the member variable.